# Most related term to a given sentence , nltk word2vec

Tags: python, nltk, word2vec

Having a trained word2vec model, is there a way to check which word in its vocabulary is the most "related" to a whole sentence ?

i was looking for something similar to

```
model.wv.most_similar("the dog is on the table")
```

which could result in ["dog","table"]

Answer (score 0):

The `most_similar()` method can take multiple words as input, ideally as the named parameter `positive`. (That's as in, "positive examples", to be contrasted with "negative examples" which can also be provided via the `negative` parameter, and are useful when asking `most_similar()` to solve analogy-problems.)

When it receives multiple words, it returns results that are closest to the average of all words provided. That might be somewhat related to a whole sentence, but such an average-of-all-word-vectors is a fairly weak way of summarizing a sentence.

The multiple words should be provided as a list of strings, *not* a raw string of space-delimited words. So, for example:

```
sims = model.wv.most_similar(positive=['the', 'dog', 'is', 'on', 'the', 'table'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i had already tried it, but as you foresaw, it doesn't provide a good result. At the moment i'm having decent results with `model.wv.n_similarity(question_words_array, [topic_word])` 

but it still isn't very good, and has the problem that i have to check for each topic